# Unhandled JS Exception: Unexpected number '.5' no stack

Tags: javascript, react-native

I'm getting the below not clear Error in the last one week

```
2022-07-25 14:25:05.002891+0300 FitAndMore[78006:725830] [Client] Updating selectors failed with: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4099 "The connection to service named com.apple.commcenter.coretelephony.xpc was invalidated: failed at lookup with error 3 - No such process." 
UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=The connection to service named com.apple.commcenter.coretelephony.xpc was invalidated: failed at lookup with error 3 - No such process.}
2022-07-25 14:25:05.003619+0300 FitAndMore[78006:725856] [Client] Synchronous remote object proxy returned error: 
Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4099 "The connection to service named com.apple.commcenter.coretelephony.xpc was invalidated: failed at lookup with error 3 - No such process." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=The connection to service named com.apple.commcenter.coretelephony.xpc was invalidated: failed at lookup with error 3 - No such process.}
2022-07-25 14:25:05.007068+0300 
FitAndMore[78006:725856] [Client] Synchronous remote object proxy returned error: Er2022-07-25 14:25:05.007332+0300 FitAndMore[78006:725833] [Client] Updating selectors failed with: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4099 "The connection to service named com.apple.commcenter.coretelephony.xpc was invalidated: failed at lookup with error 3 - No such process." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=The connection to service named com.apple.commcenter.coretelephony.xpc was invalidated: failed at lookup with error 3 - No such process.}
ror Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4099 "The connection to service named com.apple.commcenter.coretelephony.xpc was invalidated: failed at lookup with error 3 - No such process." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=The connection to service named com.apple.commcenter.coretelephony.xpc was invalidated: failed at lookup with error 3 - No such process.}

2022-07-25 14:25:05.025844+0300 FitAndMore[78006:725830] [Client] Updating selectors failed with: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4099 "The connection to service named com.apple.commcenter.coretelephony.xpc was invalidated: failed at lookup with error 3 - No such process." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=The connection to service named com.apple.commcenter.coretelephony.xpc was invalidated: failed at lookup with error 3 - No such process.}
2022-07-25 14:25:05.025844+0300 FitAndMore[78006:725856] [Client] Synchronous remote object proxy returned error: 
Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4099 "The connection to service named com.apple.commcenter.coretelephony.xpc was invalidated: failed at lookup with error 3 - No such process." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=The connection to service named com.apple.commcenter.coretelephony.xpc was invalidated: failed at lookup with error 3 - No such process.}
2022-07-25 14:25:05.050572+0300 FitAndMore[78006:725829] [Client] Updating selectors failed with: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4099 "The connection to service named com.apple.commcenter.coretelephony.xpc was invalidated: failed at lookup with error 3 - No such process." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=The connection to service named com.apple.commcenter.coretelephony.xpc was invalidated: failed at lookup with error 3 - No such process.}

2022-07-25 14:25:05.055166+0300 FitAndMore[78006:725829] [Client] Updating selectors after delegate addition failed with: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4099 "The connection to service named com.apple.commcenter.coretelephony.xpc was invalidated: failed at lookup with error 3 - No such process." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=The connection to service named com.apple.commcenter.coretelephony.xpc was invalidated: failed at lookup with error 3 - No such process.}
WARNING: Logging before InitGoogleLogging() is written to STDERR
E0725 14:25:06.978281 75517952 NativeToJsBridge.cpp:188] Attempting to call JS function on a bad application bundle: RCTLog.logIfNoNativeHook()
    Unhandled JS Exception: Unexpected number '.5'

no stack
```

[image]

My current package.json is as below

```
    {
  "name": "Youhanna",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "android": "react-native run-android",
    "ios": "react-native run-ios",
    "start": "expo start --dev-client",
    "test": "jest",
    "lint": "eslint ."
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@expo/vector-icons": "^12.0.5",
    "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "^1.15.11",
    "@react-native-community/cli": "^6.2.0",
    "@react-native-community/clipboard": "^1.5.1",
    "@react-native-community/datetimepicker": "^3.5.2",
    "@react-native-community/netinfo": "^7.1.2",
    "@react-native-community/viewpager": "^5.0.11",
    "@react-native-firebase/admob": "^11.5.0",
    "@react-native-firebase/app": "^11.5.0",
    "@react-native-firebase/messaging": "^11.5.0",
    "@react-native-masked-view/masked-view": "^0.2.6",
    "@react-native-picker/picker": "^2.2.1",
    "@react-native/normalize-color": "^2.0.0",
    "@react-navigation/drawer": "^6.1.8",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.0.6",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^6.0.11",
    "axios": "^0.24.0",
    "core-js": "^3.19.1",
    "error-stack-parser": "^2.0.6",
    "expo": "~43.0.3",
    "expo-app-loading": "^1.2.1",
    "expo-av": "^10.1.3",
    "expo-calendar": "^10.0.3",
    "expo-clipboard": "~2.0.3",
    "expo-constants": "^12.1.3",
    "expo-device": "^4.0.3",
    "expo-file-system": "^13.0.3",
    "expo-image-manipulator": "~10.1.2",
    "expo-image-picker": "^11.0.3",
    "expo-linear-gradient": "^10.0.3",
    "expo-localization": "^11.0.0",
    "expo-permissions": "^13.0.3",
    "expo-screen-orientation": "~4.0.3",
    "expo-sharing": "^10.0.3",
    "expo-splash-screen": "^0.13.5",
    "expo-status-bar": "^1.1.0",
    "expo-updates": "~0.10.13",
    "firebase": "^9.5.0",
    "i18n-js": "^3.8.0",
    "jsonfile": "^6.1.0",
    "lodash.memoize": "^4.1.2",
    "lottie-ios": "~3.2.3",
    "lottie-react-native": "~5.0.0",
    "moment": "^2.29.1",
    "native-base": "^2.15.2",
    "package": "^1.0.1",
    "prop-types": "^15.7.2",
    "react": "17.0.1",
    "react-animated-css": "^1.2.1",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-native": "0.64.3",
    "react-native-animatable": "^1.3.3",
    "react-native-app-intro-slider": "^4.0.4",
    "react-native-appearance": "^0.3.4",
    "react-native-calendars": "^1.1269.0",
    "react-native-codegen": "^0.0.11",
    "react-native-credit-card-input": "^0.4.1",
    "react-native-crypto-js": "^1.0.0",
    "react-native-datepicker": "^1.7.2",
    "react-native-device-info": "^8.4.8",
    "react-native-drawer": "^2.5.1",
    "react-native-dropdownalert": "^4.3.0",
    "react-native-easy-content-loader": "^0.3.2",
    "react-native-easy-grid": "^0.2.2",
    "react-native-elements": "^3.4.2",
    "react-native-event-listeners": "^1.0.7",
    "react-native-fs": "^2.18.0",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.10.3",
    "react-native-image-picker": "^4.3.0",
    "react-native-image-resizer": "^1.4.5",
    "react-native-image-slider-show": "^1.0.3",
    "react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view": "^0.9.5",
    "react-native-linear-gradient": "^2.5.6",
    "react-native-localize": "^2.1.5",
    "react-native-map-link": "^2.8.1",
    "react-native-material-dropdown-v2": "^0.11.1",
    "react-native-material-textfield": "^0.16.1",
    "react-native-modal": "^13.0.0",
    "react-native-navigation-apps": "^1.0.27",
    "react-native-open-maps": "^0.4.0",
    "react-native-otp-textinput": "^0.0.8",
    "react-native-paper": "^4.10.1",
    "react-native-permissions": "~3.1.0",
    "react-native-photo-upload": "^1.3.0",
    "react-native-reanimated": "~2.3.1",
    "react-native-render-html": "^6.3.0",
    "react-native-responsive-screen": "^1.4.2",
    "react-native-root-toast": "^3.3.0",
    "react-native-router-flux": "^4.3.1",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "^3.3.2",
    "react-native-screens": "~3.9.0",
    "react-native-signature-canvas": "^4.3.0",
    "react-native-skeleton-placeholder": "^5.0.0",
    "react-native-snap-carousel": "^3.9.1",
    "react-native-star-rating": "^1.1.0",
    "react-native-svg": "^12.1.1",
    "react-native-swiper": "^1.6.0",
    "react-native-swiper-flatlist": "^3.0.16",
    "react-native-tab-view": "^3.1.1",
    "react-native-tiny-toast": "^1.0.7",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^9.0.0",
    "react-native-walkthrough-tooltip": "^1.3.0",
    "react-native-web": "^0.17.5",
    "react-native-webview": "^11.14.3",
    "react-native-youtube-iframe": "^2.2.1",
    "react-navigation": "^4.4.4",
    "react-navigation-drawer": "^2.7.1",
    "react-navigation-stack": "^2.10.4",
    "react-redux": "^7.2.6",
    "react-select-3ilogics": "^0.1.1",
    "react-swiper-3ilogics": "^0.1.0",
    "redux": "^4.1.2",
    "redux-logger": "^3.0.6",
    "redux-persist": "^6.0.0",
    "rn-expo-paypal-integration": "^1.2.0",
    "tcomb-form-native": "^0.6.20"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "~7.16.0",
    "@babel/runtime": "~7.16.3",
    "@react-native-community/eslint-config": "^3.0.1",
    "babel-jest": "^27.3.1",
    "jest": "^27.3.1",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "~0.66.2",
    "react-test-renderer": "17.0.2"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  }
}
```

I've created the project one again, Deleted Cache, npm i --force and done pod install, but unfortunately issue still persist.

The error exists in both iOS and Android and also when running directly on a device.
**Please share your suggestions.**

Comment: Issue resolved after identified after SSD hardisk was crashed, someone the Lottie json file got some strange text added to it from xCode.

Answer (score 0):

Issue resolved after identified after SSD HardDisk was crashed, someone the Lottie json file got some strange text added to it from xCode.

After replacing the file with a new json content, everything back to work normally.

Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS15.5.sdk/usr/lib/swift/QuartzCore.swiftmodule/arm64-apple-ios.swiftinterface /Volumes/PortableSSD/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS15.5.sdk/usr/lib/swift/Dispatch.swiftmodule/arm64-apple-ios.swiftinterface /Volumes/PortableSSD/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS15.5.sdk/usr/lib/swift/Metal.swiftmodule/arm64-apple-ios.swiftinterface /Volumes/PortableSSD/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS15.5.sdk/usr/lib/swift/Darwin.swiftmodule/arm64-apple-ios.swiftinterface /Volumes/PortableSSD/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS15.5.sdk/usr/lib/swift/Foundation.swiftmodule/arm64-apple-ios.swiftinterface /Volumes/PortableSSD/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS15.5.sdk/usr/lib/swift/CoreFoundation.swiftmodule/arm64-apple-ios.swiftinterface /Volumes/PortableSSD/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS15.5.sdk/usr/lib/swift/DataDetection.swiftmodule/arm64-apple-ios.swiftinterface /Volumes/PortableSSD/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS15.5.sdk/usr/lib/swift/FileProvider.swiftmodule/arm64-apple-ios.swiftinterface /Volumes/PortableSSD/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS15.5.sdk/usr/lib/swift/CoreGraphics.swiftmodule/arm64-apple-ios.swiftinterface /Volumes/PortableSSD/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS15.5.sdk/usr/lib/swift/Swift.swiftmodule/arm64-apple-ios.swiftinterface /Volumes/PortableSSD/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS15.5.sdk/usr/lib/swift/UIKit.swiftmodule/arm64-apple-ios.swiftinterface /Volumes/PortableSSD/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS15.5.sdk/usr/lib/swift/_Concurrency.swiftmodule/arm64-apple-ios.swiftinterface /Volumes/PortableSSD/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS15.5.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Accessibility.framework/Modules/Accessibility.swiftmodule/arm64-apple-ios.swiftinterface /Volumes/PortableSSD/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/swift/iphoneos/prebuilt-modules/15.5/ObjectiveC.swiftmodule/arm64-apple-ios.swiftmodule /Volumes/PortableSSD/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/swift/iphoneos/prebuilt-modules/15.5/CoreImage.swiftmodule/arm64-apple-ios.swiftmodule /Volumes/PortableSSD/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/swift/iphoneos/prebuilt-modules/15.5/Combine.swiftmodule/arm64-apple-ios.swiftmodule /Volumes/PortableSSD/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/swift/iphoneos/prebuilt-modules/15.5/QuartzCore.swiftmodule/arm64-apple-ios.swiftmodule /Volumes/PortableSSD/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/swift/iphoneos/prebuilt-modules/15.5/Dispatch.swiftmodule/arm64-apple-ios.swiftmodule /Volumes/PortableSSD/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/swift/iphoneos/prebuilt-modules/15.5/Metal.swiftmodule/arm64-apple-ios.swiftmodule /Volumes/PortableSSD/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/swift/iphoneos/prebuilt-modules/15.5/Darwin.swiftmodule/arm64-apple-ios.swiftmodule /Volumes/PortableSSD/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/swift/iphoneos/prebuilt-modules/15.5/Foundation.swiftmodule/arm64-apple-ios.swiftmodule /Volumes/PortableSSD/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/swift/iphoneos/prebuilt-modules/15.5/CoreFoundation.swiftmodule/arm64-apple-ios.swiftmodule /Volumes/PortableSSD/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/swift/iphoneos/prebuilt-modules/15.5/DataDetection.swiftmodule/arm64-apple-ios.swiftmodule /Volumes/PortableSSD/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/swift/iphoneos/prebuilt-modules/15.5/FileProvider.swiftmodule/arm64-apple-ios.swiftmodule /Volumes/PortableSSD/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/swift/iphoneos/prebuilt-modules/15.5/CoreGraphics.swiftmodule/arm64-apple-ios.swiftmodule /Volumes/PortableSSD/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/swift/iphoneos/prebuilt-modules/15.5/Swift.swiftmodule/arm64-apple-ios.swiftmodule /Volumes/PortableSSD/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/swift/iphoneos/prebuilt-modules/15.5/UIKit.swiftmodule/arm64-apple-ios.swiftmodule /Volumes/PortableSSD/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/swift/iphoneos/prebuilt-modules/15.5/_Concurrency.swiftmodule/arm64-apple-ios.swiftmodule /Volumes/PortableSSD/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/swift/iphoneos/prebuilt-modules/15.5/Accessibility.swiftmodule/arm64-apple-ios.swiftmodule /Volumes/PortableSSD/Apps/fitandmore/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/Lottie/lottie-ios-umbrella.h /Volumes/PortableSSD/Apps/zobaba/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/Lottie/lottie-ios.modulemap /Volumes/PortableSSD/Apps/fitandmore/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/Lottie/lottie-ios.modulemap /Volumes/PortableSSD/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS15.5.sdk/usr/include/objc/ObjectiveC.apinotes /Volumes/PortableSSD/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS15.5.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/Headers/OpenGLES.apinotes /Volumes/PortableSSD/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS15.5.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreImage.framework/Headers/CoreImage.apinotes /Volumes/PortableSSD/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS15.5.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/QuartzCore.framework/Headers/QuartzCore.apinotes /Volumes/PortableSSD/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/swift/apinotes/Dispatch.apinotes /Volumes/PortableSSD/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS15.5.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Metal.framework/Headers/Metal.apinotes /Volumes/PortableSSD/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS15.5.sdk/usr/include/Darwin.apinotes /Volumes/PortableSSD/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS15.5.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/Foundation.apinotes /Volumes/PortableSSD/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS15.5.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/Headers/CoreGraphics.apinotes /Volumes/PortableSSD/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS15.5.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UserNotifications.framework/Headers/UserNotifications.apinotes /Volumes/PortableSSD/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS15.5.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIKit.apinotes /Volumes/PortableSSD/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS15.5.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreText.framework/Headers/CoreText.apinotes /Volumes/PortableSSD/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS15.5.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Security.fr